# layout over layout on android

Tags: android, button, textview, android-layout

I have a screen that contains there different layout.

### BigLayout [it contains all three layout]

LayoutA   - title
LayoutB   - body
LayoutC   - button
the title layout contain TextView, Button and CheckedTextView and of it in the BighLayout, if i want that the CheckedTextView will be display over the body layout, how can i do such a thing?

Comment: first of all, try it by yourself and generate some code by yourself, and if then having any difficulty then post it here, then people can try to help on by modifying your code, nobody is going to spoon feed

Answer (score 1):

if u want to show one layout over other layout u can use framelayou.
so u can take
 1] Layout A as a frame layout 
 2] layout B as a frame layout. so that u can able to show CheckedTextView over the body layout

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, but i didn't understand it, so i will be more spcipic If i have one LinearLayout that hold the CheckedTextView. and another LinearLayout that contain list , i want that when i press the CheckedTextView a part of it will be shown on the list,

Answer (score 1):

Check out the RelativeLayout, it does what you need.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer, but i didn't understand it, so i will be more spcipic If i have one LinearLayout that hold the CheckedTextView. and another LinearLayout that contain list , i want that when i press the CheckedTextView a part of it will be shown on the lis

Comment: Have you read the RelativeLayout documentation (including http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)? Have you tried to code something? If yes, can you copy/paste your layout XML and the code that changes the state of the CheckedTextView? You need to also put some effort, not just wait for the code to be written by others.